# Calculate mean, median and mode from grouped frequency table

Tags: r, media, mean, mode

If we have only grouped frequency table; for example

```
                                    (mk) (frequency) (cumulative freq)
1                             (37.9,43.1]     4      4
2                             (43.1,48.2]    16      20
3                             (48.2,53.3]    7       27
```

how can we calculate median, mode and mean using R?

The theorical relations:

**Mean**

we find the mean of each interval,suppose xi,whose frequency fi;
then mean is

```
sumof(xi*fi)/sumof(fi)
```

for my example

```
sum=4*(37.9+43.1)/2+16*(43.1+48.2)/2+7*(48.2+53.3)/2
mean=mean/27=46.2
```

**Median**

we find the interval which his cumulative frequency
-sum over all previous intervals including this interval)equal or greater than n/2
-n is the total frequency- for our example n=27 and the required interval is (43.1,48.2]
then if we use lmin  the begin of this interval here lmin=43.1,lmax the end of this interval,lmax=48.2,fi the frequency of this interval,fi=16, Fi the cumulative frequency,Fi=20 then 
median is

```
median=43.1+( ( 27/2-(20-16) )/16 ) *(48.2-43.1)=46.128
```

the relation of mode is familiar to median.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm stuck how to convert interval(here mk) from string to interval,
I know how to calculate this theorical

Comment: Let's see your theoretical calculations and maybe we can apply this to your result.

Comment: if anybody can edited to make relations clear?thanks

Comment: I edited some to get you started - but please review and try to make it clearer what you are trying to do

Answer (score 3):

**1) Means** Read in the data into character vector `L` and replace everything that is not a digit or dot with a space.  Then re-read it creating data frame `DF` whose columns are `V1`, `V2` and `V3`.  Compute the means of the boundary values of each row and replicate them `V3` times giving a vector `r` containing 4+16+7 elements.  Then take the mean, median and mode of that.  (The median and mode estimates from this may not be very good.)

```
# test data
Lines <- "(mk) (frequency) 
(37.9,43.1]     4 
(43.1,48.2]    16 
(48.2,53.3]     7"

# replace textConnection(Lines) with "myfile.txt", say
L <- readLines(textConnection(Lines))
DF <- read.table(text = gsub("[^0-9.]", " ", L), skip = 1, as.is = TRUE)

r <- with(DF, rep((V1 + V2)/2, V3))

mean(r)
## [1] 46.209

median(r)
## [1] 45.65

tab <- table(r) # frequency table
as.numeric(names(tab))[which.max(tab)]
## [1] 45.65
```

This also works directly:

```
with(DF, weighted.mean((V1+V2)/2, V3))
## [1] 46.209
```

**2) Normal** Another approach is to assume normality (or other distribution) and minimize the negative likelihood:

```
neglik <- function(x) {
   m <- x[1]
   s <- x[2]
   with(DF, -prod(V3*(pnorm((V2-m)/s) - pnorm((V1-m)/s))))
}
optim(c(mean(r), sd(r)), neglik)$par
## [1] 45.6422  3.8841
```

We can then estimate the mean, median and mode as 45.6422 .

**3) Piecewise uniform** One possible assumption is that the pdf is uniform within frequency ranges so:

```
pdf <- function(x) with(DF, {
   if (length(x) > 1) return(sapply(x, pdf))
   if (x <= min(V1) || x >= max(V2)) return(0)

   k <- sum(x > V1)
   p <- V3/sum(V3) / (V2 - V1)
   p[k]
})

cdf <- function(x) {
   if (length(x) == 1) integrate(pdf, -Inf, x)$value else sapply(x, cdf)
}

# or without integration - gives same answer as cdf
cdf2 <- function(x) with(DF, {
  xx <- unique(sort(c(V1, V2)))
  yy <- c(0, cumsum(pdf((V1 + V2)/2) * (V2 - V1)))
  approx(xx, yy, xout = x, rule = 2)$y
})

# mean
integrate(function(x) x * pdf(x), min(DF$V1), max(DF$V2))$value
## [1] 46.20939

# median - alternately could use cdf2 in place of cdf
uniroot(function(m) cdf(m) - .5, range(c(DF$V1, DF$V2)))$root
## [1] 46.12813
```

Comment: the way of calculating median is not correct,it's not necessary mean of an interval

Comment: What is correct depends on what assumptions we make.  I have added some variations with different assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you're stuck at the step of converting the text column to numeric values for `lmin` and `lmax`.

Some fiddling around with `gsub()` and `strsplit()` gives you this:

First, replicate the data:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "
  (mk) (frequency) 
1 (37.9,43.1]     4 
2 (43.1,48.2]    16 
3 (48.2,53.3]    7")
```

Then, convert the character to numerics:

```
x <- gsub("[](]", "", dat$X.mk.)
x <- strsplit(x, split = ",")
x <- matrix(as.numeric(unlist(x)), 
            ncol = 2, 
            byrow = TRUE
)
colnames(x) <- c("lmin", "lmax")
```

The result:

```
x
     lmin lmax
[1,] 37.9 43.1
[2,] 43.1 48.2
[3,] 48.2 53.3
```